# jQuery alternative for fade in/fade out of div background

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

The following code has 2 separate `<div>` elements each with an image inside. When I hover over either div the background colour fades in and then out - perfect!!

I have this web page working beautifully in Firefox, however it just doesn't play ball in IE, so I'm wondering if there is a jQuery version of achieving the same?

**Here is a jsfiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/mcgarriers/NJe63/**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .box, .box2 {
        float:left;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background:blue;
        -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    }
    .box:hover {
        background:red;
        transition: background 1s;;
        -moz-transition: background 1s;; /* Firefox 4 */
        -webkit-transition: background 1s;; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transition: background 1s;; /* Opera */
    }
    .box2:hover {
        background:black
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://www.internetlearningsociety.com/images/logos/google_logo3.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
        <img src="http://www.internetlearningsociety.com/images/logos/google_logo3.jpg" />
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Is there a simple way with jQuery to replicate what I'm trying to do with the above?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery UI you can accomplish this using [animate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/)

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "blue" }, 1000);
});

$('.box2').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "blue" }, 1000);
});;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NJe63/1/

**EDIT:**

​
just add `.children('img').hide()` `.children('img')show()` to the end

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 1000).children('img').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "blue" }, 1000).children('img').hide();
});

$('.box2').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000).children('img').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "blue" }, 1000).children('img').hide();
});;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NJe63/2/

You can use fadeIn,fadeOut for the image

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('img').stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('img').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
});

$('.box2').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('img').stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);

}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('img').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NJe63/3/

You can use opacity to fade in and out the image.. but since the google logo is inside as a child element it will fadein/fadeout with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/NJe63/5/

Comment: Perfect!!!
Out of interest, if I were to change `.box` from being `mouseenter - bgimage / mouseleave - no bgimage`, how could I do this?

So instead of colours, try a bg image?

Comment: oh...  just an image.. let me see

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help here.
Yes, basically wanting to try fade in/out a bg image *behind* the existing google logo one - so basically just replacing the colour effect with 1 image.

Comment: @mcgarriers I added with just the image fadein/fadeout function.

Comment: Thank you, wirey.
I think I have to explain a little better. Can you hold on one moment while I re-phrase? :)

Comment: Basically, is it possible to KEEP the Google logo unanimated throughout - however replace the BLUE to RED fade with a NON-IMAGE to IMAGE fade? This will be a background image.

Is this possible?
Sorry to mess you around. Will accept answer shortly as you did answer correctly - I'm just asking a slightly different question.

Comment: @mcgarriers I made another edit.  Only way I can think of making that possible is to move the logo outside of the div and position it over the div.  Since it's a child of the div it will fadeOut/fadeIn with it

Comment: Aaaah ok. I'll have a think of how to do this so the google logo doesn't fade out. thank you so much for all your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to fade in or out a background image other than with css3, which isn't supported in oldIE. The only workaround would be to literally place images behind a transparent div and fade in and out those images (or divs with image backgrounds).

Comment: Whoops. Maybe I didn't explain. I don't want to fade in/out a background image - just the background colour.
Is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: I believe you can use jQuery UI for this. See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: Not if an image is involved. You can transition from one background color to another though using jQuery UI iirc.